# Modificar variable dentro de un método (o funcióon) en JAVA

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        float a = 0,b = 0;

        prueba.mod1(args);        
        System.out.println("El resultado es: " + (a+b));

    }

    public static void mod1(String[] args) {

        float a,b;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduzca el 1er numero:");
        a = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el 2º numero:");
        b = sc.nextFloat();
    }

}
```

Independientemente de los valores que le de a las variables a y b, me va a imprimir como resultado 0

Comment: para que tienes dos void main?

Comment: El problema se da por que estas encapsulando los valores. Te explico, tu método mod1 tiene declaradas las variables a y b. Es decir que aunque el método sea estático los valores a y b de dicho método solo tienen valor cuando se ejecuta el método mod1. Que pases por argumentos el args no le da acceso a las variables a y b declaradas en el main. Si lo que quieres es asignar a y b quitalos del método mod1 y de main y agrégalos de manera estática como variables globales de la clase prueba. (Por cierto por convención las clases deben empezar con mayúscula)

Answer (score 2):

Imprime `0` porque los valores de `a` y `b` que declaras aquí:

```
    float a = 0,b = 0;
```

nunca son modificados realmente.

Puedes hacer dos cosas:

#### Declarar las variables como miembros de la clase y modificarlas entonces desde dentro del método `mod1`.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Main {
       private static float a = 0,b = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

//        float a = 0,b = 0;
        mod1();        
        System.out.println("El resultado es: " + (a+b));

    }

    public  static void mod1() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca el 1er numero:");
        Main.a = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el 2º numero:");
        Main.b = sc.nextFloat();
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Una prueba de este código:

```
Introduzca el 1er numero:
23
Introduzca el 2º numero:
587
El resultado es: 610.0
```

#### Modificar el método `mod1` haciendo las operaciones dentro de él.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Main {
 //      private static float a = 0,b = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        mod1();        

    }

    public  static void mod1() {
        float a = 0,b = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca el 1er numero:");
        a = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el 2º numero:");
        b = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("El resultado es: " + (a+b));

        sc.close();
    }

}
```

El resultado de una prueba:

```
Introduzca el 1er numero:
543
Introduzca el 2º numero:
97
El resultado es: 640.0
```

---

Otras formas son posibles, por ejemplo, hacer que `mod1` retorne los valores obtenidos en el Scanner para luego sumarlos, pero eso no sería muy lógico en el ejemplo de código que muestras...

He corregido algunas cosas también: en tu código abres un Scanner para no usarlo nunca. El Scanner de `mod1` no lo cierras. Quité los argumentos `String[] args` del método `mod1`... esos parámetros no tienen sentido allí.